# How eclpiselink manage table locks?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipselink

I need some aproach or help to visualize a problem im having. The thing is, I work in an application Java 6, database mysql, ecpliselink 1.0.1, glassfish 2.1.

Sometimes some of the functionalities have problems to access the database, and seeing the log I found this:

```
    Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 1.0.1 (Build 20080905)): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
Error Code: 1205
Call: UPDATE table_person SET sip_codigo_barra_bat_64 = ?, sip_version = ? WHERE ((sip_id = ?) AND (sip_version = ?))
bind => [null, 2, 89608, 1]
```

Searching another Stackoverflow post I fond out that it could be a dead-lock, and in my code there is a method that could be the problem, but I have some doubts of how elcpiselink manage the locks.

1-If my Java method doesnt have any lock annotation, Eclipselink lock the table anyways? or depends of the poolconnection? or what?

2-If three threads execute the same Java method at the same time and the method execute for the same table a SELECT, then an UPDATE, and then another UPDATE that could generate a dead-lock? how?

3-I think that the problem I have is a deadlock in a method that does something like this, it modify two tables: table_person and table_payment (table_payment has a foreing key to table_person)

```
public void method(Integer id){

//Select table_person element from database
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * from table_persona where id=id", Pèrson.class);
tablePersonElement=q.getResultList().get(0);

//Select table_payment from database
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * from table_payment where id_table_persona=id", Payment.class);
tablePaymentElement=q.getResultList().get(0);

//If tablePaymentElement element doesnt exists is created 
if(tablePaymentElement==null){
  tablePaymentElement=new Payment();
  tablePaymentElement.setMoney(money);
  tablePaymentElement.setIdTablePerson(tablePersonElement);
  em.persist(tablePaymentElement);
  em.flush();
}else{
  tablePaymentElement=new Payment();
  tablePaymentElement.setMoney(money);
  tablePaymentElement.setIdTablePerson(tablePersonElement);
  em.merge(tablePaymentElement);
  em.flush();
}

//Finally it set some values of tablePerson and save it
tablePersonElement.setValue(value);
em.merge(tablePersonElement);
em.flush();
}
```

Is possible to generate a deadlock with this method? or in case that other method update something of table_person while this one is executing?

Comment: LockWaitTimeout doesn't mean deadlock, it just means it timed out waiting for a lock. A deadlock is when two processes each hold a lock but need the one held by the other - a stale mate. Timeouts help prevent this, as if you can't get the lock you need in some period, the exception causes that process to release all its locks. You need to check why you are getting the timeout, as it could be just bad performance of some long running transactional process. Locks are in the database; while Eclipselink maintains locks, they are mostly post transactional to do with how it merges changes into cache

Comment: I'd suggest not calling 'flush' so often. This forces statements to the database - multiple inserts/updates for the same TablePaymentElement instance when it can do everything in one. It is odd you are using a native SQL query over top EclipseLink like this - and it is pointless when you take a new Payment instance and just call merge with it anyway; merge performs an insert if the instance doesn't exist yet, so the query for tablePaymentElement is unnecessary. This method might be exposed by locks from other processes; make sure you have the id_table_persona fk indexed